# Is RTSP streaming over http supported in Windows 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, rtsp

I am creating a video streaming App in Windows 8.1 with RTSP streaming. Just want to know if anyone can tell me if RTSP streaming mode is supported in Windows 8.1 App. If not What is the work around for that?

Comment: Has anything changed since question was asked or maybe you have found better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTSP is not supported in-box, but one could create a MediaStreamSource to interpret the stream. A quick search didn't find any RTSP samples out there, but see the [MediaStreamSource streaming sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff#content) to get started with MediaStreamSource.